# Android move object to touch

Tags: java, android, graphics, imageview

I'm kinda new to building apps on Android. I do have some Java developing experience, but the project I do now is first on Android.

I'm building a basic cards game, and I want the card to move to the specific location I touch.
I did it, and the card moves to the touch point, but once the animation is over it bounces back to starting position.

I added a Image re-position code, but now it begins the animation from that point.
any ideas, anyone?

the code I did is:

```
    public class FinallyActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        EditText DBG;
        ImageView iv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        DBG = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        iv =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imV1);      
    }

    private void RunAnimations(MotionEvent event) {
    //  Animation b = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.cardtrans);
        int xStart, yStart, dx, dy;

        xStart = iv.getLeft();
        yStart = iv.getTop();
        Animation b = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE,0,Animation.ABSOLUTE,event.getX()-50,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE,0,Animation.ABSOLUTE,event.getY()- 105);
        b.setDuration(3000);
        iv.clearAnimation();
        iv.startAnimation(b);   

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            RunAnimations(event);
        }

                iv.layout((int)event.getX()-25,(int) event.getY()-105,
                (int)event.getX()+25,(int) event.getY()-35);
        return true;

    }

}
```

Thanks All!!

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-animations-explained.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

b.fillAfter(true)

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter%28boolean%29)

Comment: as a follow up question, does anybody knows a great book\site to learn graphics and animation from, for complete begginers? (I work with android SDK and some blogs, but I cant seem to catch the thing on a deep level)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.subview);
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    xDown = event.getX();
                    yDown = event.getY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    float moveX,moveY;
                    moveX = event.getX();
                    moveY = event.getY();

                    float distanceX = moveX -xDown;
                    float distanceY  = moveY -yDown;
                    imageView.setX(imageView.getX()+distanceX);
                    imageView.setY(imageView.getY()+distanceY);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: float xDown = 0;
    float yDown = 0;

Comment: Thanks for answering. To improve your answer, please include some text explaining your solution.